# Find closest element in complete document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have indexed my document using Jquery `index` Given a certain index value, I would like to 'locate' the 'nearest' element with some `class`. This will not work for me:

```
$(variableIndexNumber).closest('.class');
```

The reason is that sometimes the `.class` changes its position, meaning it could be anywhere in the document. Sometimes its a sibling, sometimes a parent, sometimes way up in document or in the bottom. So the usual selctors `next` `closest` `first` `nextAll` etc don't work for me (because of document tree)

What can I try to get the nearest `.class` relative to some other element (given by variable)?

Comment: There s/is/should be only *one* element with that particular id?

Comment: @Bergi No there could be many (class is better example, will change that in question..)

Comment: @Youss No, there can not be multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: @Ray Nicholus Thats way I changed it in class. (and yes there could be many same ids, but its not good)

Comment: @Youss "It's not good" is an understatement.  It violates the spec.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: @Youss what do you mean by closest element? For example, if an element is a siblings and another one is a grand-parent, which one is the closest for you???

Comment: If it can be *anywhere*, you'll have to search the whole DOM with `$('.class')`. Or what exactly do you mean by "*nearest*"?

Comment: Guys, I changed the question. Its not about id. In my haste I typed ID but its about elements instead. So lets go for classes..

Comment: @Samuel Caillerie In that case both, but that would be an odd sitution in my case (wouldnt happen)

Comment: @Youss thus can you explain exactly which type of algorithm you would use in order to determine the *closest* element (I think it is the key here!)...

Comment: @Samuel Caillerie Not sure that I understand...Im not using anything I guess. Its just a html document. So for instance Im trying to locate span at index 39. If it is not there it will give me undefined in console. So the next step would be "take the index number and start searching from there in to all directions untill you come across the span and do something with it" Thats basicaly the kind of code I need:)

Comment: @Bergi yes "search the whole DOM" but the element should be the nearest considering dom tree (doesnt matter if its up the tree or down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.prevUntil('.class')`, `.nextUntil('.class')`, `.parentsUntil('.class')`, then compare their sizes.

Whichever one has the least size is the closest to the element in terms of DOM structure.

**UPDATE**: In the process, you will also need `.andSelf()`, `.filter()` and typical `.next()` and `.prev()` to actually get to the target you want. Demo has been updated. You can see that now the code is more generic.

You'll probably need a sorting function too, as I've did in the proof-of-concept below.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/FzA78/

Side-note: There's no `.childrenUntil()`, because that's branching outwards the DOM tree, not inwards towards the document root, in case you're wondering. But my guess is, you could do a `$('.me').find('.class')` first, then for each of them, do a `.parentsUntil('.me')` instead, then compare the sizes. I'm not sure if this would work though.

Comment: Made a correction, should be `.parentsUntil()`, not `.parents()`

Comment: Youss, any doubts? Makes sense?

Comment: @Terry Young I still have to implement it in to my project but it looks great and exactly what I whas looking for. Thanks for sticking around and putting up the 'example(complete code)'. Also very funny how you put up the code:)

Comment: Actually, I've updated the demo, I'll edit the answer to mention what else you might need