# Jquery : find closest h2 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to find closest h2 tag to hovered image following is my html code

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding-left:0;">
      <div class="ih-item square effect7"><a href="#">
         <div class="img">
         <img src="images/facilities/facility1.png" class="img-responsive fullwidthimg">
         </div>
        <div class="info">
          <h3>Content </h3>
          <p>Some content </p>
        </div></a>
     </div>
 <h2>Arenas</h2>
 </div>
```

this is what i am trying to do in jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.img').hover( function(){
          $(this).closest('h2').hide();  
    })
})
```

Please help me how can i do it .

Comment: change your code to this `$(this).closest('h2').hide();`,you need to include your tag in single/double qoutes for css selector to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the closest ancestor element that has a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194578/find-closest-element-in-complete-document

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) only looks up the ancestor tree. You need a more complex traverse since the `<h2>` is not an ancestor

Something like:

```
 $('.img').hover( function(){
      $(this).closest('.ih-item').siblings('h2').hide();  
 });
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).sibling is not a function

Comment: ooops...is a typo ...is `siblings()` with an `s`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method to get the correct ancestor and find for `h2` tag:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img').hover(function() {
    $(this).parents().eq(2).find('h2').hide();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding-left:0;">
  <div class="ih-item square effect7">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="img" style="border:2px solid red;">
        <img src="images/facilities/facility1.png" class="img-responsive fullwidthimg">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Content </h3>
        <p>Some content </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <h2>Arenas</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

PLease go through below code, It will help you. Amending @mathiasfc's code so once you hover on image taxt will hide and on hover out you can get it back.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img').hover(function() {
    $(this).parents().eq(2).find('h2').hide();
  },function(){
  $(this).parents().eq(2).find('h2').show();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding-left:0;">
  <div class="ih-item square effect7">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="img" style="border:2px solid red;">
        <img src="images/facilities/facility1.png" class="img-responsive fullwidthimg">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Content </h3>
        <p>Some content </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <h2>Arenas</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you were missing quotes on h2 :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.img').hover( function(){
              $(this).closest('.col-md-3').find('h2').hide();  
        })
    })
```

this should work

Answer (score -1):

You have to think in your tree first, mainly because you are manipulating your DOM **tree**. My approach in this situation is go to the first-child node and find your `h2` tag, after that make your treatment.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.img').hover( function(){
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('h2').hide();  
        })
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9b9s87oo/1/

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Badacadabra That's true, let's make our community better 1% day-by-day. I made an edit.